# Filters for potentiometer potentially causing issues with ADC

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, adc

I am sampling potentiometers on an Arduino Zero using the SAMD21 microcontroller.

Listed on the SAMD21 datasheet the ADC input is 3.5 kiloohms of impedance.

On my setup I am using a low pass filter by simply using a RC filter. The issue is if I used a smaller resistor with a larger capacitor I seem to get resistor loading with the potentiometer. The voltage divider isn't directly proportional to the potentiometer's position due to the loading effect (shown in picture 1.)

Using a a higher resistor value with a lower capacitor value fixes the loading affect. The correct voltage divider comes out of the potentiomter.

I am just concerned that the high resistance of the filter affects the analogue signal going into the ADC. Shown in picture 2 is the current setup. The 3.5k resistor represents the input impedance of the ADC in of the Arduino. In the second picture it shows only approxiamtely 50 mV  going into the ADC.

Would this scenario happen in a real world application or would the ADC input receive the 1.615 volts with no issue with a setup like the one in picture 2?

Picture 1

Voltage from wiper arm of potentiomter not having 50/50 voltage divider.

[image: Voltage from wiper arm of POT not having 50/50 voltage divider]

Picture 2

Voltage from wiper arm of the potentiomter has 50/50 voltage divider split but not getting that same voltage at ADC in.

[image: Voltage from wiper arm of POT has 50/50 voltage divider split but not getting that same voltage at ADC in]

Comment: What does the datasheet say? I can tell you modelling the input impedance with a resistor is wrong. I can also tell you your 10nF cap should be sufficient to counter the charging of the adc sampling capacitor. Have you measured the actual voltages?

Answer (score 1):

You have misread the datasheet. The ADC input does not have input impedance of 3500 ohms to ground. Your simulation has 3500 ohms to ground so a series resistor of 100k will form a resistor divider network and thus explains your simulation having low voltages at the ADC input.

You can fix the simulation by just removing the 3500 ohm resistor.